# Building multiple shared libraries with one Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm trying to build multiple shared libraries in one makefile. This is what I'm using to build one shared library:

```
CC = gcc # C compiler
PWD := $(shell pwd)
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g # C flags
LDFLAGS = -shared  # linking flags

RM = rm -f  # rm command

CFLAGS += $(DFLAGS)

TARGET_LIB := lib1.so # target lib
#TARGET_LIB += lib2.so

SRCS := lib1.c # source files
#SRCS += lib2.c # source files

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET_LIB)

$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

However, I can't just uncomment the lines for lib2 and have it being built as well. It's likely because `$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJS)` expands to `lib1.so lib2.so : lib1.o lib2.o` which isn't what I want.

Instead, I want something like

```
lib1.so : lib1.o

lib2.so : lib2.o
```

But I'm not sure how to do so or what it is called. Can someone tell me what to do to achieve what I'm looking for?

EDIT: I should have been more clear. I realize you can add more targets to build these. But is there a way to do it without having to write a new target everytime I want to add a new library?

Thanks.

Comment: the make variable $(INC) is not defined, so the libraries will (*probably) not be compiled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this -

all : lib1.so lib2.so

and provide rules to make lib1.so and lib2.so

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by separating targets like this:

```
CC = gcc # C compiler
PWD := $(shell pwd)
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g # C flags
LDFLAGS = -shared  # linking flags

RM = rm -f  # rm command

CFLAGS += $(DFLAGS)


TARGET_LIB1 = lib1.so # target lib
TARGET_LIB2 = lib2.so
TARGET_LIBS = $(TARGET_LIB1) $(TARGET_LIB2)

SRCS1 = lib1.c # source files
SRCS2 = lib2.c # source files
SRCS = $(SRCS1) $(SRCS2) 

OBJS1 = $(SRCS1:.c=.o)
OBJS2 = $(SRCS2:.c=.o)
OBJS = $(OBJS1) $(OBJS2)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET_LIBS)

$(TARGET_LIB1): $(OBJS1)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(TARGET_LIB2): $(OBJS2)
    $(CC) $(INC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: TARGET_LIB is not defined, so the suggested make file will not work.  $(INC) is not defined, so the source files will (probably) not compile correctly.

Comment: I've completed the makefile, I thought it was obvious that it is not a full complated makefile, and only meant to show how to do it. $(INC) was used but not defined in the original makefile. but it is not an error! it is just blank variable. In makefile you can pass arguments from other makefile including the current, so it also can be declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate sources of two libraries into different directories. It also may help in further maintenance of your libraries. Then use one make file which will trigger corresponding sub-makefiles. I may be better than one big makefile

Answer (score 0):

The implicit rules are for that.  Read about them in the GNU Make manual.

Replace

```
$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJS)
```

with

```
%.so: %.c
```